# Best Way to Reset iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode4.5

xCode 4.5 will occasionally hang when building and running when the app under development is running in the simulator. The anticipated response is the app running in the simulator will stop and the new build will be started in the simulator. This state will not allow xCode to stop tasks or close/quit.  xCode responds that there are tasks in process and will not stop these tasks.  Is there a preferable solution other than force quitting xCode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xCode will not allow a quit action because tasks are running and will not stop or build in current state.

Ignore xCode state
  Change simulator type in xCode's device scheme
  Build/run app in the new simulator, this may cause the developer's app to crash in the simulator.
  Change device scheme back to original selection.
  Build/run app

Comment: You may really want to explain your second solution a bit more to make this an answer that others can benefit from.

Answer (score 3):

Actually quitting the simulator 99% of the time solves the issue.
Right click on simulator icon --> Quit

And Xcode will build the new version and launch it in the simulator

Answer (score 3):

In some cases quitting the simulator does not help, then you should do 
`iOS Simulator->Reset Content and Settings...` 
this will kill all applications on your simulator, but sometimes it is very useful though.